# Classes & Functions -

Tags: python, function, class, instance

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, as I am almost absolutely certain that I've referenced variables and all correctly.

I'm fairly new to using functions, and have just started learning to use Python classes a day ago.

So when I run the code, I get this error message:

```
line 37, in pathlist
    while self.no_of_files > 0:             #self.number_of_files
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'no_of_files'
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with my sequential steps of code, or is that because I've converted the numfiles input to an int() in line 20 of code.

I have attached my code below. Please help me out thanks in advance :)

```
import csv
import numpy as np


''' DEFINING MAIN CONTROL'''

def main():
    no_of_files    # = number_of_files()
    a = Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models()
    a.no_of_files()   #  = no_of_files
    a.pathlist()
    a.out_path()
    a.open_read_write_files()


''' DEFINING CLASS OF ALL '''
class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:

    def __init__(self, no_of_files):
        self.no_of_files = no_of_files

    def number_of_files():
        numfiles = input("Enter the number of files to iterate through: ")
        numfilesnumber = int(numfiles)
        return numfilesnumber

    no_of_files = number_of_files()


    def pathlist(self):
        filepathlist = []
        while self.no_of_files > 0:             #self.number_of_files
            path = input("Enter the filepath of the input file: ")
            filepathlist.append(path)
            no_of_files = no_of_files - 1
        return filepathlist

    list_filepath = pathlist(no_of_files)

    def out_path():
        path = input("Enter the file path of output path: ")
        return path

    file_out_path = outpath()

    def open_read_write_files():
        with open('{d[0]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput, open('{d[1]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput2, open('d{[2]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput3, open('{d}'.format(d=file_out_path), 'w') as csvoutput:
            reader, reader2, reader3 = csv.reader(csvinput, csvinput2, csvinput3)                                               #1: Decision Forest, 2: Boosted Decision Tree, 3: ANN
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n', fieldnames = ['oldRMSE', 'Decision Forest Regression RMSE', 'Boosted Decision Tree Regression RMSE', 'Neural Network Regression RMSE', 'Old Accurate Predictions', 'Old Inaccurate Predictions', 'Decision Forest Accurate Predictions', 'Decision Forest Inaccurate Predictions', 'Boosted Decision Tree Accurate Predictions', 'Boosted Decision Tree Inaccurate Predictions', 'Neural Network Accurate Predictions', 'Neural Network Inaccurate Predictions'])

            #######################################
            #For Decision Forest Predictions
            headerline = next(reader)
            emptyl=[]
            for row in reader:
                emptyl.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            DecFSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        DecFSqResidSum = float(cell) + DecFSqResidSum
            DecFSqResidAvg = DecFSqResidSum / len(emptyl)
            DecForest_RMSE = np.sqrt(DecFSqResidAvg)

            #Constructing No. of Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            DecisionForest_Accurate = 0
            DecisionForest_Inaccurate = 0
            Old_Accurate = 0
            Old_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-2] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        Old_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        Old_Inaccurate += 1
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        DecisionForest_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        DecisionForest_Inaccurate += 1


            ######################################
            #For Boosted Decision Tree
            headerline2 = next(reader2)
            emptyl2=[]                                      #make new csv file(list) from csv reader
            for row in reader2:
                emptyl2.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            OldSqResidSum = 0
            BoostDTSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl2:                             #make Sum of Squared Residuals
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-4]:
                        OldSqResidSum = float(cell) + OldSqResidSum
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        BoostDTSqResidSum = float(cell) + BoostDTSqResidSum
            OldSqResidAvg = OldSqResidSum / len(emptyl2)    #divide by N to get average
            BoostDTResidAvg = BoostDTSqResidSum / len(emptyl2)
            oldRMSE = np.sqrt(OldSqResidAvg)               #calculate RMSE of ESTARRTIME & Boosted Decision Tree
            BoostedDecTree_RMSE = np.sqrt(BoostDTResidAvg)

            #Constructing Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            BoostedDT_Accurate = 0
            BoostedDT_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl2:
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        BoostedDT_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        BoostedDT_Inaccurate += 1



            ######################################
            #For Artificial Neural Network (ANN) Predictions
            headerline3 = next(reader3)
            emptyl3=[]
            for row in reader3:
                emptyl3.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            ANNSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl3:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        ANNSqResidSum = float(cell) + ANNSqResidSum
            ANNSqResidAvg = ANNSqResidSum / len(emptyl3)
            ANN_RMSE = np.sqrt(ANNSqResidAvg)

            #Constructing Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            ANN_Accurate = 0
            ANN_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl3:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        ANN_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        ANN_Inaccurate += 1



            #Compile the Error Measures
            finalcsv = []
            finalcsv.append(oldRMSE)
            finalcsv.append(DecForest_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDecTree_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(Old_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(Old_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(DecisionForest_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(DecisionForest_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDT_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDT_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_Inaccurate)



            #Write the Final Comparison file
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows({'oldRMSE': row[0], 'Decision Forest Regression RMSE': row[1], 'Boosted Decision Tree Regression RMSE': row[2], 'Neural Network Regression RMSE': row[3], 'Old Accurate Predictions': row[4], 'Old Inaccurate Predictions': row[5], 'Decision Forest Accurate Predictions': row[6], 'Decision Forest Inaccurate Predictions': row[7], 'Boosted Decision Tree Accurate Predictions': row[8], 'Boosted Decision Tree Inaccurate Predictions': row[9], 'Neural Network Accurate Predictions': row[10], 'Neural Network Inaccurate Predictions': row[11]} for row in np.nditer(finalcsv))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give a no_of_files params when create 
 a Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models instance by calling def **init**(self, no_of_files).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `self` to the signature of `number_of_files()`, `out_path()`, and `open_read_write_file()`:

```
class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:

   def __init__(self, no_of_files):
       self.no_of_files = no_of_files

   def number_of_files():
      numfiles = input("Enter the number of files to iterate through: ")
      numfilesnumber = int(numfiles)
      return numfilesnumber

   def pathlist(self):
      filepathlist = []
      while self.no_of_files > 0:             #self.number_of_files
          path = input("Enter the filepath of the input file: ")
          filepathlist.append(path)
          no_of_files = no_of_files - 1
      return filepathlist

    def out_path(self):
      path = input("Enter the file path of output path: ")
      return path


    def open_read_write_files(self):
       pass
```

However, if you wish to retain the properties of a function within the class, you can use the `classmethod` decorator:

```
class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:

   def __init__(self, no_of_files):
       self.no_of_files = no_of_files
   @classmethod
   def number_of_files(cls):
      numfiles = input("Enter the number of files to iterate through: ")
      numfilesnumber = int(numfiles)
      return numfilesnumber

   def pathlist(self):
      filepathlist = []
      while self.no_of_files > 0:             #self.number_of_files
          path = input("Enter the filepath of the input file: ")
          filepathlist.append(path)
          no_of_files = no_of_files - 1
      return filepathlist
    @classmethod
    def out_path(cls):
      path = input("Enter the file path of output path: ")
      return path

    @classmethod
    def open_read_write_files(cls):
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class definition, you have `list_filepath = pathlist(no_of_files)`. This is calling `pathlist` with `no_of_files` as `self`. `no_of_files` is an `int`, so `while self.no_of_files > 0:` is attempting to access the `no_of_files` attribute of a `int`.

The full Traceback shows this. It is helpful to post the full Traceback when looking at a problem like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redacted", line 17, in <module>
    class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:
  File "redacted", line 38, in Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models
    list_filepath = pathlist(no_of_files)
  File "redacted", line 32, in pathlist
    while self.no_of_files > 0:             #self.number_of_files
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'no_of_files'
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 22, in <module>
    class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:
  File "", line 43, in Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models
    list_filepath = pathlist(no_of_files)
  File "", line 37, in pathlist
    while self.no_of_files > 0:            
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'no_of_files'`

Comment: Sorry that I didn't include the full traceback in the OG post, thought it didn't matter as much as I had to manually remove the file directory as it contained some confidential stuff.

Comment: My answer explains why you are getting that specific error. When looking at a traceback, try to walk through it in your head.